# How to change language in a .sty file?

Tags: languages

I am writing my bachelor thesis using TeXMaker. There is a `.sty` file available for us to use. The default language used by the `.sty` file is Czech and I want to change that to English.

There is a Czech and English version of each element on the title page, such as:

```
%% School name
\newcommand\skola@cz{České vysoké uČení technické v~Praze }
\newcommand\skola@en{Czech Technical University in Prague}
```

The `.sty` file lists following options:

```
\DeclareOption{semestral}%semestral project
    {\TT@diplomafalse \TT@bachelorfalse \TT@semestraltrue}
\DeclareOption{bachelor}%bachelor thesis
    {\TT@diplomafalse \TT@bachelortrue \TT@semestralfalse}
\DeclareOption{diploma}%diploma thesis
    {\TT@diplomatrue \TT@bachelorfalse \TT@semestralfalse}
\DeclareOption{cvutstyle}% title page styled according to requirements
    {\TT@cvutstyletrue}
\DeclareOption{english}% title page in English
    {\TT@englishtrue}
```

I thought I would change the language to English by changing this:

```
\usepackage[
  cvutstyle,
  bachelor,
]{thesiscvut}
```

to this:

```
\usepackage[
  cvutstyle,
  bachelor,
  english
]{thesiscvut}
```

However, this - as far as I can see - does not do anything at all. When I change "bachelor" to "diploma"  it works as expected (it shows Diploma thesis instead of Bachelor thesis on the title page).

EDIT:

This is the code for a complete minimal document demonstrating the problem:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                  %%
%%  BAKALÁŘSKÁ PRÁCE -  Database Output Storage Support in PyWPS Framework          %%
%%               Jan Pišl                           %%
%%                                                  %%
%% pro formátování využita šablona: http://geo3.fsv.cvut.cz/kurzy/mod/resource/view.php?id=775  %%
%%                                                  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\documentclass[%
  12pt,                     % Velikost základního písma je 12 bodů
  a4paper,                  % Formát papíru je A4
  oneside,                  % Oboustranný tisk
  pdftex,                   % překlad bude proveden programem 'pdftex' do PDF
%%%  draft
]{report}                   % Dokument třídy 'zpráva'
%

\newcommand{\Fbox}[1]{\fbox{\strut#1}}

\usepackage[english, czech]{babel}  % použití češtiny, angličtiny
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Kódování zdrojových souborů je UTF8

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{leftmargin=*} % bez odsazení

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatletter

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage{cmap}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\addtolength{\jot}{1em} 

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage[
    unicode,                
    breaklinks=true,        
    hypertexnames=false,
    colorlinks=true, % true for print version
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
]{hyperref}         

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Pseudokód}% Update algorithm name
\def\ALG@name{Pseudokód}

\usepackage[
  cvutstyle,          
  bachelor,           
]{thesiscvut}


\newif\ifweb
\ifx\ifHtml\undefined % Mimo HTML.
    \webfalse
\else % V HTML.
    \webtrue
\fi 

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Obrázek}
\def\figurename{Obrázek}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%% Definice informací o dokumentu  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Název práce
\nazev{Database Output Storage Support in PyWPS Framework}
{Možnosti integrace databázového úložiště v rámci frameworku PyWPS}

%% Jméno a příjmení autora
\autor{Jan}{Pišl}

%% Jméno a příjmení vedoucího práce včetně titulů
\garant{Ing.~Martin~Landa,~Ph.D.}

%% Označení programu studia
\programstudia{Geodézie a~kartografie}{}

%% Označení oboru studia
\oborstudia{Geodézie, kartografie a~geoinformatika}{}

%% Označení ústavu
\ustav{Katedra geomatiky}{}

%% Rok obhajoby
\rok{2018}

%Mesic obhajoby
\mesic{leden}

%% Místo obhajoby
\misto{Praha}

%% Abstrakt
\abstrakt{Bude doplněno} {To be implemented.}

%% Klíčová slova
\klicovaslova
{PyWPS, databáze, Python, GDAL}
{PyWPS, databases, Python, GDAL}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Nastavení polí ve Vlastnostech dokumentu PDF
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\nastavenipdf
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Začátek dokumentu
\begin{document}

\catcode`\-=12  % pro vypnuti aktivniho znaku '-' pouzivaneho napr. v \cline 

% aktivace záhlaví
\zahlavi

% předefinování vzhledu záhlaví
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase
    {%
    \thechapter.%
    \ #1}}{}}

% Vysázení přebalu práce
%\vytvorobalku

% Vysázení titulní stránky práce
\vytvortitulku

% Vysázení stránky s abstraktem
\vytvorabstrakt

% Vysázení prohlaseni o samostatnosti
\vytvorprohlaseni

% Vysázení poděkování
\stranka{%nahore
       }{%uprostred
       }{%dole
       \sffamily
    \begin{flushleft}
        \large
        \MakeUppercase{Poděkování}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{1em}
        %\noindent
    \par\hspace{2ex}
    {Bude doplněno.}
}

% Vysázení obsahu
%\obsah

% Vysázení seznamu obrázků
%\seznamobrazku

% Vysázení seznamu tabulek
%\seznamtabulek



% Vysázení seznamu zkratek
%\include{zkratky}

% Literatura
\nocite{*}
\def\refname{Literatura}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{literatura}


% Začátek příloh
\def\figurename{Figure}%
\prilohy

% Vysázení seznamu příloh
%\seznampriloh

% Vložení souboru s přílohami
%\include{prilohy}

% Konec dokumentu
\end{document}
```

This is the .sty file:

http://textuploader.com/dq6ej

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide code for a complete minimal document demonstrating the problem. If we need a custom sty file, provide a link.

Comment: Does `\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{thesiscvut}` help?

Comment: your question is unrelated to texmaker that is just the editor in which you are writing the document, but the question is about a package `thesiscvut` the documentation of that thesis package will tell you how to select the english versions, the answer will be specific to that package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it does not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, you are right it doesnt relate to texmaker, sorry. i didnt realize that. I have added a link to the thesiscvut.sty file. I am going through it but cannot find anything useful.

Comment: that's what I tried first: 
`usepackage[
  cvutstyle,
  bachelor,
  english
].`

It doesnt work.

Comment: @JanPisl: Unclear questions/incomplete code provoke comments which guessing around

Comment: all the `\xxxx@en` commands defined are used if the `english` option is used as far as i can see, but it is hard to look just by eye you should make a small test file that has an `english` option but Czech words are being generated, and add it to your question.

Comment: I think it would be best to make a bug report to maintainers of this package. From looking at the package code, they choose method for language selection which is quite hard to maintain. I would use something like [translations](https://ctan.org/pkg/translations) package.

Answer (score 2):

The `english` option is only partially implemented.

I picked on one word, faculty (I guess:-) and prefixed each use by `!!`

so around line 856

```
    \ifTT@english %
        \MakeUppercase{!!1\fakulta@en} \\[0.4em] %
    \else %
        \MakeUppercase{!!1\fakulta@cz} \\[0.4em]
```

note that would use english

but the version at line 908 only has

```
                    \MakeUppercase{!!2\fakulta@cz} \\
```

at line 1021 again it tests for english

```
\ifTT@english %
    \MakeUppercase{!!3\fakulta@en} \\[0.4em] %
\else
    \MakeUppercase{!!3\fakulta@cz} \\[0.4em] %
\fi %
```

but actually your page uses this version (`!!4`) at line 1094

```
            \sffamily \Large    
                \MakeUppercase{!!4\fakulta@cz}\\
                \MakeUppercase{\programstudiatext@cz
```

which again does not test for English.

the simplest thing to do is use this command which ought to define the Czech and English versions but

```
%% Definice fakulty
\def\fakulta#1#2{%
    \renecommand{\fakulta@cz}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\fakulta@en}{#1}%
}
```

as you see it uses `#1` for both so defines them to be the same thing, however if you only want the english version then

```
\fackulta{English word}{}
```

will define it to be whatever you want.